# A holiday postcard - 'We eat ' or 'We're eating.......in a restaurant every day'

Tags: tense, present-continuous, present-simple

When writing a postcard from holidays. One should write: We eat in a restaurant or we're eating in a restaurant? Most sources I've found suggest Present Simple - 'every day'. However in this case it's a temporary situation (a week).....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the situation will be true for the entire duration of the vacation, "We eat..." fits a little bit better. If it's a temporary situation within the vacation that you are describing, the present continuous fits better:
"Currently, we are eating in a restaurant every day, at least until we find a room with a kitchenette."

But it makes very little difference, because a card sent home while on holiday describes a temporary situation. It won't be misunderstood.

Comment: So, Present Continuous in that case would be correct as well? To me, it's much more suitable. As we use it with 'this month', 'this term'......'This holiday I'm dining at a restaurant every day'. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You can use present continuous for cases where you want it to be clear that what you are talking about is temporary. If you are talking about what you do all the time, then the simple present fits better. So, yes, if you are specifying a particular time frame, the continuous is better, because giving an explicit time frame suggests that you aren't talking about what you do all the time.